# M2n68-am PLUS support Server Ram?

Tags: memory

I have an asus motherboard m2n68-am plus. my question is, can i use server ram into it? i read the motherboard manual and it says-Supported Ram Integrity Check = Non-ECC,ECC. does it mean i can use server ram? Thanks . . .

Comment: First of all, how do you define "server RAM". From the question I am guessing want you to split with ECC in the "server RAM" category and without ECC (so possibly with or without parity) as "desktop RAM". How about buffered.registered vs unbuffered/unregistered?  Secondly, what about the memory leaks tag? (programs or drivers which are badly written can use memeory and forget to free it. That is a memory leak. It has nothing to do with physical memory or compatability.  3) There is a lot more to RAM that just ECC or !ECC. E.g. speed, type (FPM, SDRAM, DDR, DDR2, DDR3, DDR4, CAS, RAS, ....)

Comment: ... ranks, voltage. None of this are mentioned in the post and noone can gibve you the answer you want.  Last two: Why the memory limit and the memory management tags. Totally different items again.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your motherboard supports (only) DDR2, so you will not be able to use SDRAM, DDR, DDR3, or DDR4. So don't even consider anything that's not DDR2.

[These](http://stores.ebay.com/GeeK-NoiZe-Memory-and-More/RAM-Types-Explained.html) are the types of RAM that are commonly used.

Within DDR2, we have:

- "Regular" desktop DDR2: DIMMs that are *not* Fully Buffered, *not* Registered, and *without* Error Correcting Code (ECC). A.K.A. UDIMMs
- "Workstation" DDR2: DIMMs that are *not* Fully Buffered, *is* Registered, but *do have* ECC. A.K.A. RDIMMs
- "Laptop" DDR2: UDIMMs that are smaller in size for use on laptops. A.K.A. SO-DIMMs
- "Server" DDR2: DIMMs that *are* Fully Buffered, *are* Registered, and *do* have ECC. A.K.A. FB-DIMMs

Of these categories, I am absolutely certain that the "Laptop" and "Server" categories are **incompatible** with your motherboard. You will find this out immediately if you try to stick a module into your RAM slot: the notch on the RAM stick won't line up with the notch in your slot (and in the case of the SO-DIMM, it won't even be nearly the same physical size as your RAM slot).

I am also absolutely certain that the "Desktop" category above **is** compatible with your motherboard.

The one I am uncertain about is the "Workstation" category above. A general rule of thumb with these things is that *if it's mechanically compatible* (if it will enter into the slot cleanly without any unnecessary force or bending or damaging of the RAM or the slot), then it *should* be compatible to use as well. However, without owning any DDR2 Registered RAM, I'm going to say it's [not compatible based on this Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052UXFBY) (the reviews and questions).

**To be on the safe side and avoid unnecessary time and expense, you should only buy RAM that your motherboard manual or technical specs sheet explicitly says it supports.**

Here's further proof that DDR2 FB-DIMMs *do not* work with desktop motherboards. [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_Buffered_DIMM)

[image: fb-dimm different from regular udimm picture]